# why the concepts of partial derivatives and differentiability need a open set?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

In order to define the limit of a function $f: A \subset \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ at a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$ we need $x_0$ to be a limit point of $A$.

But in order to speak about partial derivatives and differentiability of $f: A \subset \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ at $x_0 \in A$ we need to ensure that $A$ is open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I dont know if this is a fact, but my textbook, before any definition or theorem that involves those concepts, it always says at the beginning *let $A$ be a open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$ ...*

So could someone explain what is the precise (maybe topological) explanation?

Thank you

Comment: replace "an open-set containing $x_0$" by "a neighborhood of $x_0$"

Comment: The idea of differentiability tells us about how a function behaves near a point, and in the usual topology on $\mathbf{R}^n$, open sets guarantee that there is a neighborhood in the domain to talk about. It is not clear in general what a derivative should represent at boundary points or worse, isolated points of a domain. (Although in some cases it can make sense to define these things, for instance if the derivative is bounded and continuous)

Comment: So in general it is meaningless to difine the derivative of $f$ in 'bad' points of $A$ since our goal, when we difine the differentiability, is to aproximate $f$*good enough*, from all directions @enthdegree Could you give me a link of a example of such a case, in order to have a complete view?